# Initialise object properties with dictionary that may not contain all required keys (and fail the initialisation in that case)

Tags: json, swift, initialization

I'd like to initialise an object with the contents of JSON dictionary.

The object's model has mandatory properties (the "must"s; e.g. a name, id, number of bananas, ...) and non-mandatory properties (the "maybe"s; e.g. a description).

During initialisation, a JSON dictionary is passed as an argument. The initialisation should fail (return nil) if one of the musts is missing in the dictionary (i.e. if the key isn't there). It should succeed if one or more of the maybes is missing (and keep the default value).

The following is roughly what I want:

```
class Model {

    var must1:  String = ""
    var must2:  String = ""
    var maybe1: String = "default1"
    var maybe2: String = "default2"

    init?(dict: Dictionary<String,String>) {

        must1 = dict["must1"] //and if not possible return nil
        must2 = dict["must2"] //and if not possible return nil

        maybe1 = dict["maybe1"] //and if not possible ignore
        maybe2 = dict["maybe2"] //and if not possible ignore

    }

}
```

In the real project I have a lot more properties and I'm mainly trying to avoid an inelegant solution.

I've been thinking of ways I could bring the *guard* statement or optional binding (*if let*) into play, but I'm relatively new to swift and can't see an obvious solution right away.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
class Model {

    var must1:  String = ""
    var must2:  String = ""
    var maybe1: String = "default1"
    var maybe2: String = "default2"

    init?(dict: Dictionary<String,String>) {

        guard let must1 = dict["must1"] else {
            return nil
        }        

        guard let must2 = dict["must2"] else {
            return nil
        }

        self.must1 = must1
        self.must2 = must2

        if let maybe1 = dict["maybe1"] {
            self.maybe1 = maybe1
        }

        if let maybe2 = dict["maybe2"] {
            self.maybe2 = maybe2
        }
    }

}
```

It is very good that you are rolling your own JSON deserialization code, it is going to help you understand how the process work.

Once you'll feel confident you might want to have a look at libraries like [JSONCodable](https://github.com/matthewcheok/JSONCodable), which take away all that mundane coding.

As a side note, I would suggest you consider using `struct` instead of `class`, and `let` instead of `var`. Unless you have specific needs to pass models around by reference and/or need mutability, it is usually better to use immutable structs for models in Swift.

**Update**

As @MartinR suggests in the comments, you could also have the checks for the `mustX` in the same guard:

```
guard let must1 = dict["must1"], must2 = dict["must2"] else {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The two `guard` statements could be combined into one: `guard let ..., let ... else ...`.

Comment: Good point @MartinR, I've updated the answer incorporating your suggesdion.

Comment: Didn't you mean "`let` instead of `var`"? Also in the guard statement, all `let`s except the first one are optional.